# python - does return on a threading.Thread class free all the memory?

Tags: python, memory-management, python-multithreading

I have this class, which at some point will call on_close(), how do I make sure that my thread will be closed and all the memory used freed? Is putting a return in on_close() enough?
Also, is it safe to run 500+ threads? Noob questions, I know.. But I'm trying to learn!

```
class MyClass(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self): pass
     def do_stuff(self): pass
     def on_close(self): 
           more_stuff()
           return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [gc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#module-gc) module may help you in forcing the garbage collector to run.

Regarding your second question, In modern PC you can run up to around 4000 threads, **BUT** Python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) creates an absurd situation, where running multiple python threads on a multi-core PC will be slower than running the same program on a single-core. [David beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/) explains this perfectly in one of his lectures.